# Compile a Razor component file programmatically

Tags: .net, razor, blazor

How do I generate a compile a Razor component (Blazor component) file into a class programmatically?

My goal is to compile and load the class file dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I’m understanding, but just to be clear: You want to take some runtime parameters, combine them with a template to create a new Blazor component, compile it in real-time, and then load it for immediate use in the same application? Out of curiosity, what’s the motivation for doing this? There are a couple of approaches, each with their own challenges. But I imagine it’ll be easier for the community to address those approaches with more information about the broader problem you’re looking to solve.

Comment: I have the contents of a Razor template that I want to compile into a class file. I need to know what parameters should be used with the Razor compiler to do so. I remember watching a video about the Razor tooling but cannot find it. Nor do I find the actual code for this in the ASP.NET Core repo.